# Setup Microsoft Azure SAML 2.0 into iOS application

Tags: ios, azure, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to configure single sign-on feature of SAML 2.0 in my iOS application.
I have successfully configured Auth2.0 using MSAL iOS SDK.

Link: https://cocoapods.org/pods/MSAL

I have also looked into docs also.
LinkL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol

But I am unable to figure out way to integrate SAML 2.0 by MSAL iOS sdk.

I am not sure whether MSAL iOS SDK provide support for SAML 2.0 integration or not.

In BASIC SAML Configuration section, I need to provide "identifier" and "Reply URL"

[image]

I am not sure, what I need to provide in these options. Currently in attached picture, I have used dummy url for now.

Pardon me for my poor grammar.

**Does anyone know how to setup SAML 2.0 in iOS application.**

Comment: identifier is your app's entityID. replyUrl is where Azure will redirect the browser after authentication. It's all browser based

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the complete answer from Microsoft support.

If anyone want, then he/she can take a look on this url:

https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/14212/setup-microsoft-azure-saml-20-into-ios-application.html